# Prevent href from opening link but still execute other bind events

Tags: jquery, events, click, preventdefault

I want to prevent links from opening pages. So I have written this :

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
}
```

which is great! But this blocks my other event :

```
$(".toolbar a").click(function(e) {
    ...action...
}
```

Sure I can add my action to the first event with some test, but is there an elegant way to prevent **only** href event from executing?

**EDIT**

In fact it works, sorry. See @raina77ow fiddle working here: http://jsfiddle.net/HeFS6/

Comment: what do you mean by other events..? Can you show that in code ...?

Comment: Well, `e.preventDefault()` doesn't block event propagation; it does exactly what you need. Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HeFS6/) for an example of 'generic-specific' mix; what's different in your code?

Comment: I'd suggest checking [this article](http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/) as well; it shows the differences between four event-messing statements in jQuery.

Comment: Indeed it works, I might have problems with the binding events. It works now, and I don't find my problematic code back. Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 35):

Use `return false` instead. You can see the code below working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ErickPetru/J3rYu/).

```
​$("a").click(function() {
    return false;
});

$(".toolbar a").click(function() {
    alert("Do something");
});​
```

As pointed by *@raina77ow* with [this article](http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/), using `return false` is the same as calling `event.preventDefault()` and also `event.stopPropagation()`. As I had troubles without `return false` on some codes in the past, I always suggest it.

But the most importante thing here is **the bind order**: your last bind will be your first executed code. So, take care about it and go.

Comment: It's plain wrong: `return false` = `event.preventDefault();    event.stopPropagation();`

Comment: Well, `return false` don't stop the event bubbling. What is wrong with this sentence? I'm not talking about `preventDefault()` or `stopPropagation()` but just suggesting the use of `return false` that never caused troubles in my codes.

Comment: `return false` is equivalent to calling both `.preventDefault()` and `.stopPropagation()` (but not `.stopImmediatePropagation()`). Hence it _does_ stop the event bubbling. Please check the article I've linked in the comments to this question.

Comment: I know this article. I guess I was not clear: `return false` not stop the spread of the events that were linked by jQuery. I was not talking about the native JavaScript event bubbling. Well, the code solves the OP problem, but I will update the answer with the article link as well.

Comment: I'm sorry, but how exactly does `return false` solve the OP's problem? ) It does nothing more to NOT prevent the native event bubbling than `.preventDefault()` does.

Answer (score 1):

In place of `e.preventDefault()`, have you tried `return false`? This should also prevent browser default behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

There is no href event.  That is what you'd end up with if prevent default on click.  You should just use more specific selectors.