# containing ajax data to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using jquery ajax to simply load my website/PWA content into a `div`. The problem is the webpage inside of the `div` content is a social network and it has multiple links inside that are clickable and when clicked the window opens the links, breaking my customized header and footer. Is there a way to contain all the links clicked inside of the `div` contained to the `div` itself. Something similar to an iFrame. If that makes any sense. Does it help if the social network is a headless wordpress?

```
$('IdOfButton').click ( function () {
     $('content').load ('/signinup.php') ; 
} );
```

Comment: Just apply [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299227/prevent-href-from-opening-link-but-still-execute-other-bind-events) using your div's ID as part of the selector.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing id or class selector in both of your selectors

JQuery selector can be class selector `$('.class')` or id `$('#id')`
if you put no selector, like `$('content')` it will search for `<content>` elements

Comment: this is correct but how does this keep the links from opening and breaking my header and footer?

Comment: you can't, but I think what you are looking for are iframe containers. In fact, $.load() puts html directly into your element. so when you click a link, it acts in the main window and so does break your other elements.